# Do there exists any Order Complete Field at all?

Tags: ordered-fields

It is known that any two Order-Complete Fields are isomorphic. So there can exist at most 1 Order-Complete Field up to isomorphism.

Is there a way to tell that there exists one Order Complete Field?

Answer (score 1):

The reals field $\mathbb R$ is one.

Comment: Can we prove that $\mathbb{R}$ is an Order Complete field? i.e can we prove LUB Axiom?

Comment: That is a result that is proven in any construction of $\mathbb R$.

Comment: If LUB Property can be proved. Why do we take it as an axiom? and not a theorem?